# Nginx Performance Measurement

Tags: python, performance, nginx, zeromq, bottle

I want to test the load nginx can take. For that I have to make large number of request to nginx which it can process simultaneously. Is there any way of doing that?

I want to use python for writing script, I can also use zeromq for this purpose.

Comment: [`ab`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [several existing programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking#Tools_for_benchmarking) for this. No need to reinvent the wheel here.